# Change the Color and Font of QString or QLineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt4, qstring, qlineedit

How can I change the color and font of QLineEdit?

Here is my code:

```
self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(widget)
self.lineEdit.setText("enter keywords here") #I want this to be in italics and in brown color
```

The `setText` line from [Documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html#setText) says the text inside is of QString how can I change it's font and color?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the Color use `QPallete`, then use `{your palette}.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, {your QColor})`, and the font use `QFont`

My Solution:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

from PyQt4 import QtCore


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtGui.QLineEdit()
    palette = QtGui.QPalette()
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, QtCore.Qt.red)
    w.setPalette(palette)
    font = QtGui.QFont("Times", 15, QtGui.QFont.Bold)
    w.setFont(font)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: @learncode 
QLineEdit is QWidget's child, therefore, will have the parent methods.

Comment: @learncode I use Qt Widget documentation, and I look in List of all members, including inherited member: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit-members.html

Answer (score 4):

You can change the color with:

```
self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(x,x,x)")
```

Font size with:

```
self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("fontName='Times-Italic'")
```

Comment: Thanks! I am Able to change the color, But not able to change the font?

Answer (score 0):

in pyqt5 also you can do it with StyleSheet in this way:

```
qrc = """
 /* Main LineEdit Setting */
 QLineEdit{
    background-color: #18181d;
    color: red;
    border-radius: 20%;
    height: 2.6em;

    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
 }

 /* when in hover */
 QLineEdit:hover{
    background-color: #25252d;
 }

 /* when has focus */
 QLineEdit:focus{
    border: 2px solid #13c386; 
    background-color: #25252d;
 }
"""
self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet(qrc)
```